# angular-charts not working with requirejs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angular-chart

i am trying to use angular-chart but i couldn't figure how to add dependencies correctly. 
i am getting following error
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined**
in the angular-chart.js

```js
(function (factory) {
  'use strict';
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
      define(['angular', 'chart.js'], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // Node/CommonJS
      module.exports = factory(require('angular'), require('chart.js'));
  } else {
    // Browser globals
    factory(angular, Chart);
  }
}(function (angular, Chart) {
  'use strict';

  Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
  ....
```

because both **angular** and **chart** are undefined.

my require config is

```js
'use strict';
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/',
    paths: {
  'angular': '/scripts/angular',
  'angular-route': '/scripts/angular-route',
  'ui-bootstrap': '/scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.min',
  'angular-animate': '/scripts/angular-animate.min',

  'chart': '/scripts/chart',
  'angular-chart': '/scripts/angular-chart',
  
  'data-utils': '/common/data-utils',
  'string-utils': '/common/string-utils',

        'app': '/config/app',
        'routes': '/config/routes'
    },
 shim: {
  'app': {
      deps: ['angular', 'angular-route', 'ui-bootstrap', 'data-utils', 'string-utils', 'angular-chart']
  },
  
  'angular-route': {
   deps: ['angular']
  },
  'ui-bootstrap': {
      deps: ['angular', 'angular-animate']
  },
  'angular-animate': {
      deps: ['angular']
  },
  'angular-chart': {
      deps: ['angular', 'chart']
  }
 }
});

require
(
    ['app'],
    function(app)
    {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'app']);
    }
);
```

my controller is

```js
define(['app'], function(app)
{
 app.controller('homeController',
    [
        '$scope',
        function($scope)
        {
            $scope.page =
            {
                title: 'Welcome to Easy Stitch'
            };

            $scope.labels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
            $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];

            $scope.data = [
              [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
              [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
            ];
        }
    ]);
});
```

every other dependency is working fine except for this one. please if anyone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure that I have to correct the dependency in my require config file and after that it is working fine.

```js
require
(
    ['app'],
    function(app)
    {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'chart.js', 'app']);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can modify the angular-chart.js:

chart.js  =>  chart,

```
(function (factory) {
  'use strict';
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module
    define(['angular', 'chart'], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // Node/CommonJS
    module.exports = factory(require('angular'), require('chart'));
  } else {
    // Browser globals
    factory(angular, Chart);
  }
```

Comment: Try to look over this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288001/how-to-use-chart-js-with-angular-chart-using-requirejs I am having the same issue as like yours. But not going to sucseed! Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It seems angular-chart expects the Chart.js module to be called "chart.js":

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define(['angular', 'chart.js'], factory);
} ...
```

Chart.js itself uses anonymous define ([ref](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/v1.0.2/Chart.js#L2007)), so it is up to you to name it. You are naming it "chart":

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        ...
        'chart': '/scripts/chart', 
        ...
```

So, just call it `'chart.js'` in the `paths` configuration!

Comment: Try to look over this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288001/how-to-use-chart-js-with-angular-chart-using-requirejs I am having the same issue as like yours. But not going to sucseed! Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

After installing angular-chart with bower, I had to change

```
define(['angular', 'chart'], factory);
```

into

```
define(['angular', 'Chart'], factory)
```

because Charts.js will export Chart and not chart.